# jquery validation IE Object doesn't support property

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate

I am using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). If i try to set custom field to highlight it shows an error only in IE (tested on IE11 and IE10). Console error is `Object doesn't support property or method 'closest'` and points to the line in "highlight" part.

The code is:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#formPost_connection").validate({
        rules: {
            mail: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            mail: {
                required: "Please enter your email address or username"
            }
        },
        errorElement : 'div',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            var parent = element.closest('.form-group');
            error.insertAfter(parent);
        },
        highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            var parent = element.closest('.form-group');
            $(parent).addClass('field-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            var parent = element.closest('.form-group');
            $(parent).removeClass('field-error');
        }
    }); 
});
```

HTML of form is:

```
<form id="formPost_connection" autocomplete="on" method="POST" name="" action="">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="account_login">Email address / User name:</label>
                            <div class="input-wrapper">
                                <input id="account_login" type="text" name="mail" title="Enter your email address or user name" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="password-field-wrapper">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <label for="mdp">Password:</label>
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input id="mdp" type="password" name="mdp" title="Enter your password" required />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a title="Did you forget your password?" class="forgot-password" href="/reset-password">Forgot your password?</a>
                        </div>    

                        <button class="btn" type="submit">Log In</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Comment: jquery-1.11.2.min.js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks to be an issue with how the element value is passed in IE, in IE it is a dom element reference not a jQuery object.

Just wrap element with jQuery like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formPost_connection").validate({
        rules: {
            mail: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            mail: {
                required: "Please enter your email address or username"
            }
        },
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var parent = $(element).closest('.form-group');
            error.insertAfter(parent);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
            var parent = $(element).closest('.form-group');
            $(parent).addClass('field-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
            var parent = $(element).closest('.form-group');
            $(parent).removeClass('field-error');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ssxo1r17/)

Comment: possible without jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I thought it was worthwhile updating.

The object passed in is a dom element, and will always be a dom element. Contrary to [Arun P Johny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30297980/4266091)

The issue is that all browsers apart from ie have implemented their own experimental closest functionality, allowing the closest function to be used directly on dom elements; This means jquery was not required for those browsers to perform the closest functionality, this is why it appears to be an IE only bug. In fact it is not a bug the code written is at fault.

This was implemented on chrome on 03/03/2015, only 2 months before this question.

The correct approach currently, as explained by Arun P Johny's answer is:

```
$(element).closest('.form-group')
```

For further information on the experimental closest functionality please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest