# Getting Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup, modal-dialog

I am using this jquery popup plugin [from this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170808060543/http://dixso.github.io:80/custombox/) on my WordPress site. It's working fine on all browsers but giving the following error on IE11.

[image]

Comment: @JohnDoe, can you provide a working example?

Comment: @pragya, please put your some code so we can judge what is issue... my be it's is issue with dom element not found or have same id multiple time on page.

Answer (score 122):

As others have mentioned, the [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method is not supported in IE, but there is a polyfill available, just include it "before" your plugin declaration:

```
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  Object.assign = function(target) {
    'use strict';
    if (target == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
    }

    target = Object(target);
    for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
      var source = arguments[index];
      if (source != null) {
        for (var key in source) {
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
            target[key] = source[key];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return target;
  };
}
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Test page: http://jsbin.com/pimixel/edit?html,js,output (just remove the polyfill to get the same error you're getting on your page).

Comment: Why does it use single `!=` instead of safer `!==`?

Comment: Thank you!  This works beautifully.  I was having this exact problem with the Facebook Customer Chat widget, and applying this code just before FB's code did the trick.  (For the one client who still insists upon using IE even though the rest of the world has moved on)

Comment: Something similar is available here https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-object-assign -- I added it with npm install... and copied the automatic polyfill as suggested by `<script src="<your-libs-directory>/object-assign-auto.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 8):

@John Doe

I figured out from your comment that you want to implement this in node/react stack. This is very different from original question and you should have asked your own ;)
Anyways, Heres what you need to do...

You can use [es6-object-assign][1].  It is an ES6 Object.assign() "polyfill".

First, in `package.json` in your root folder, add `es6-object-assign` as a dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    "es6-object-assign": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "^0.12.0",
    ...
  },
```

Then if you want to use it in node environment use:

```
require('es6-object-assign').polyfill();
```

If you are having the issue on front (browser) end...
Add it in your index.html file...

```
<script src="location_of_node_modules/es6-object-assign/dist/object-assign.min.js"></script>
<script>
  window.ObjectAssign.polyfill();
</script>
```

`location_of_node_modules` depends on boilerplate you use, mostly just `node_modules`, but sometimes when index.html is in a subdirectory you need to use, `../node_modules`

Answer (score 7):

As per the documentation, Object.assign() is a new technology, part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

And it is not supported by IE.

Comment: How do you implement a polyfill like https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-source-polyfill? In a node/react stack?

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution for this problem:

> Add the script legacy.min.js before the custombox.min.js

source: [custombox github project](https://github.com/dixso/custombox/issues/143)

Answer (score 3):

@Andres-Ilich has the right answer to your question but you're asking the wrong question:

Why not just use a jQuery plugin that supports IE like Zurb's excellent Reveal: https://github.com/zurb/reveal

It will do everything you want and not throw this error.

Answer (score 3):

Currently working on a jQuery popup myself:
https://github.com/seahorsepip/jPopup

Has everything you'd expect of a popup and more :D

Anyway back on topic, I'm currently writing version 2 which is a big rewrite and adds support for IE6 (version 1 was IE7+) and ran into a similiar error...

Original code that gave the error in IE6:

```
//Insane code for an insane browser
this._vars.fakeScrollbar = $("<div style=\"position:absolute;top:expression(document.documentElement.scrollTop);right:0;bottom:0;margin-left:-200px;width:0;overflow-y:scroll;height:expression(document.documentElement.clientHeight);z-index:9999999;\"></div>");
```

The hack I had to come up with:

```
//Insane code for an insane browser
this._vars.fakeScrollbar = $("<div>");
this._vars.fakeScrollbar.html("<div style=\"position:absolute;top:expression(document.documentElement.scrollTop);right:0;bottom:0;margin-left:-200px;width:0;overflow-y:scroll;height:expression(document.documentElement.clientHeight);z-index:9999999;\"></div>");
this._vars.fakeScrollbar = this._vars.fakeScrollbar.children();
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged the question with jQuery you can use the jQuery [extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) function. No need for a polyfill and it does deep merge as well.

For Example:

```
var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: { weight: 52, price: 100 },
  cherry: 97
};
var object2 = {
  banana: { price: 200 },
  durian: 100
};

// Merge object2 into object1
$.extend( object1, object2 );
```

Result:

```
{"apple":0,"banana":{"price":200},"cherry":97,"durian":100}
```

Answer (score 3):

please add script

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-object-assign@1.1.0/dist/object-assign-auto.min.js"></script>
```

to html file to resolved this problem.

Comment: Worked like a charm on my ReactJS app in Laravel, thanks mate :)

Answer (score 2):

These error usually occurs when some html element id has the same id as some variable in the JavaScript function. After changing the name of one of them code worked.

Source : [SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975922/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-ie)

Other link : [jquery validation IE Object doesn't support property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297980/jquery-validation-ie-object-doesnt-support-property)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `Object.assign` isn't supported by all browsers, however, it's possible to re-assign it at `Object` case it's not supported by the current browser.

It's pratice to make a polyfill function, which behaves in the same way as `Object.assign(target, ...)` of ES6.

I think the best solution is to iterate each argument after `target`, assign each property of `arguments` objects to `target`, considering a iteration between objects and arrays, to avoid creating references. Optionally, to not lost instances, you can detect if the last instance of the property is only equal to `"Array"` or `"Object"`, and doing so you won't lost a `Image` interface (e.g) if you plan to create new references, but objects with these instances will still be reference.

**Edit**: the original `Object.assign` doesn't work in this way.

According to this solution, I've my own polyfill which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38755270/#38755337).

Answer (score 0):

## React solution for IE11

Regarding [shramee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39050080/6225838), which stated something like this:

> *@JohnDoe* from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215360/getting-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-assign#comment65287392_38960147), you want to implement this in **node/react** stack. This is very different from the original question, but you might use [es6-object-assign](https://github.com/rubennorte/es6-object-assign), an ES6 `Object.assign()` "polyfill":

This polyfill was updated and things can be done a bit differently now:

- in `package.json` in your root folder, add `es6-object-assign` as a dependency (executing `npm i` in a command line after):

  ```
  "dependencies": {
      "es6-object-assign": "^1.0.2",
      "react": "^16.8.6",
      ...
    },
  ```

  **Or** simply run: `npm i --save es6-object-assign`
- To use it in a node environment:

  ```
  require('es6-object-assign').polyfill();
  // Same version with automatic polyfilling
  require('es6-object-assign/auto');
  ```
- To use it in your *index.html*, just add the **automatic polyfill JS file** reference to it (if you have scripts in the `<body>` that invoke `Object.assign()` you may add it at the end of the `<head>` element).

  1. Invoking directly from `node_modules`:

     ```
     <script src="location_of_node_modules/es6-object-assign/dist/object-assign-auto.min.js"></script>
     ```

     `location_of_node_modules` depends on your project structure (when *index.html* is in a subdirectory you might need: `../node_modules`).
  2. However, this might have not worked for you (due to `node_modules` folders access, e.g. you are using [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/)). If so, just copy the JS file from the `dist/` node_modules folder to the [`public/` folder](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder) and then:

     ```
     <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/object-assign-auto.js"></script>
     ```

     You might want to use the non-minified file and add other customized polyfills (e.g. `startsWith`).