# FLOT crosshair working, but 'legends' needs to be re-initialized

Tags: flot, legend

All,

I am trying to have the crosshair track the three waveforms.

[image]

The crosshair does show up, and the tracking does not (oops ... see **EDIT**) take place. Please note - as specified in the picture - that the legend for the horizontal bar is simply a DIV styled to look like a legend from FLOT.

The CodePen can be found [here](http://codepen.io/vpappano/pen/JbvEom)

As the program is executed, the 'legend' becomes null, and the strings do not update ... the code is:

```
legends = $(".legendLabel");

legends.each(function () {
    // fix the widths so they don't jump around
    $(this).css('width', $(this).width());
});
```

I ended up having to put this code in the updateLegend() function. The question is 'why'? Am I sitting on a time bomb?  :-)  :-)

On a side note, thank you again to [Raidri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610249/raidri) for getting me started earlier in the day.

**-- EDIT --** The tracking DOES take place (I had managed to fix it in the middle of posting the question). The only doubt I have is about having to re-initialize variable 'legend' in function updateLegend()

**-- EDIT 2 --** The code works in Chrome and Firefox, but fails in IE: 'Object doesn't support property or method "assign"'. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215360/getting-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-assign)

The code below will fix the problem ...

```
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  Object.assign = function(target) {
     'use strict';
     if (target == null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
     }

     target = Object(target);
     for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        var source = arguments[index];
        if (source != null) {
          for (var key in source) {
             if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
                target[key] = source[key];
             }
          }
        }
     }
     return target;
  };
}               

$.each(data1, function (idx, item) {
    Object.assign(item, {
        stack: true,
        lines: {show: false, steps: false },
        bars: {show: true, horizontal:true, width: 1}
    });
});
```

Comment: Works fine for me (in Chrome) with the code only outside the `updateLegend()` function. Which browser do you use? Putting the code in the `updateLegend()` should be no problem.

Comment: @Raidri ... Apologies ... My code is indeed working (see my EDIT). Thank you for your reply. I won't worry about having to re-initialize 'legends' in 'updateLegends()'. Thank you again ... :-)

Comment: @Raidri ... A couple of things ... (1) The code is now working without problems (no need to re-init 'legends') -- don't know why, but I'll take it   ...  (2) The code works in Chrome and Firefox, but fails in IE (see my **EDIT 2**)