# Angularjs Load object into array via forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of Drug Codes `'BARB', 'HALU', 'METH'`.   I want to loop thru these codes and create a new object for each one.

```
var saveObj = {};
saveObj.SelectedList = [];
angular.forEach(self.DrugNamesSelected, function(value, key) {
    //Load Objects into array
    var newObj = {};
    newObj = self.Selected;
    newObj.FK_CLNT_PERSFK_PER = $routeParams.personId;
    newObj.DRUG_TYP_CODE = value;
    saveObj.SelectedList.push(newObj);
});
```

This is what I'm getting

> saveObj.SelectedList[0].DRUG_TYP_CODE = 'METH'
>   saveObj.SelectedList[1].DRUG_TYP_CODE = 'METH'
>   saveObj.SelectedList[2].DRUG_TYP_CODE = 'METH'

This is what I need

> saveObj.SelectedList[0].DRUG_TYP_CODE = 'BARB'
>   saveObj.SelectedList[1].DRUG_TYP_CODE = 'HALU'
>   saveObj.SelectedList[2].DRUG_TYP_CODE = 'METH'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `newObj = self.Selected;` making you a problem. So what happening is each element is storing a reference of `self.Selected`(i.e. all objects are referring to single memory reference). So as last value updates to `METH`, all 3 elements has same `self.Selected` value.

```
angular.forEach(self.DrugNamesSelected, function(value, key) {
    //Load Objects into array
    var newObj = {};
    //newObj = self.Selected; //removed this line
    newObj.FK_CLNT_PERSFK_PER = $routeParams.personId;
    newObj.DRUG_TYP_CODE = value;
    saveObj.SelectedList.push(newObj);
});
```

If you need that particular object assignment for some reason, I'd suggest you to use `Object.assign` which will copy `self.Selected` properties to `newObj`.

```
Object.assign(newObj, self.Selected)
```

---

IE11 doesn't support `Object.assign` out of the box. You could consider adding polyfill for the same from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215360/getting-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-assign)

Comment: Object.assign doesn't work for ie(11) so I had to add a polyfill function. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215360/getting-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-assign)