# Using Vue in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, webpack

I am new to Vue but I thought I'd give it a go in a recent project, I can see why its liked. Anyway, everything was going great until I switched over to IE, where nothing worked at all.

With errors such as `Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'` I gave it a Google and apparently IE doesn't support ES6 very well, according to this question: [Getting Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215360/getting-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-assign)

So, I'd heard of Babel and it looked like the sort of thing that would do the job as it is capable of converting from ES6. Following this I attempted to integrate Babel into my Laravel project.

I updated my `webpack.min.js` as follows:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mix Asset Management
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
| for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
| file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
|
*/

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .webpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    })
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

if (!mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.webpackConfig({
            devtool: 'source-map'
        })
        .sourceMaps();
} else if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}

mix.browserSync({
    proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000'
});
```

The env package refers to: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env

However, this did not seem to solve my problem.

Should I just use `mix.babel` instead?

Comment: Normally you would use `npm run dev` to compile for development. I suppose that is what laravel mix helps with that is it wraps around tools to compile assets code to compatible ones. Have you made use of Laravel mix properly?

Comment: I ran dev and it made no difference

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: IE11 is the version I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a polyfill: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill

Import that as the first line in your entry (app.js).

However, I'd recommend using [vue cli](https://cli.vuejs.org) instead of laravel mix entirely.

Comment: I've literally spent hours looking at this o_O... is there a way to load it via Mix? Also, why should I scrap Mix for vue-cli?

Comment: All you need to do is `import "@babel/polyfill";` as the first line in app.js. Mix should handle the rest. Vue CLI handles everything pretty much out of the box and supports webpack 4. It's a much better build tool all around.

Comment: Okay, does Mix utilize babel to some degree anyway? As `require` is not a native JS function