# Kedro viz blank page

Tags: python, server, localhost, visualization, kedro

I created a sample pipeline that works correctly with `kedro run`, however when I try to visualise it with `kedro viz` I'm getting basically a blank page, even though the terminal doesn't show a single error. The only detail I've found was in the inspection mode:

[image]

The operating system I'm running it on is windows 10, when I launch it on WSL everything is completely normal.

Kedro version: 0.18.14
Kedro viz version: 6.6.1

Any ideas why it is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a time I figured out the solution. It was a dependency conflict. Reinstall your environment and it will start working.

It also solved problems with gridsearchcv on njobs > 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue affecting some Kedro-Viz installations: https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro-viz/issues/1500

You can leave a comment there describing your setup.

Comment: I had left a comment there before coming here :)

Comment: Is there any chance it'd be fixed soon? From the outside it seems to be a pretty simple reactjs bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545336/render-react-app-in-ie-11-gives-me-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-ap. If you need more information on the params/builds let me know!