# Our Java web application stopped showing the map when running on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, java, struts, jsapi

One of our applications works with google maps using jaspi to show a map and search locations. Today the users complained that the map will appear blank. First thing I did was to try myself on Chrome, and the map worked just fine, however when I tried on IE11 the maps was blank. Firefox works fine too.
I did some debugging and saw the following errors:

**- Loading Maps API with the jsapi loader is deprecated.**

**- SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'**

The application is written in Java Struts, JS, HTML, JSAPI and running over Tomcat.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215360/getting-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-assign)

Comment: Not really, it is confusing and doesn't seem to be related to Maps JavaScript API. Thank you anyway.